# How fix Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

how i can fix this error in PDO ?
This bug occurs when I want to use other classes next to this class.
Codes are bug or should I add code ? please guide me !
My config file : (The database is mysqli)

```
$db_name = "a";
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_pass = "c";
$db_user = "b";
try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_pass);
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "connection failed !";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

code :

```
class verify
{
    public $licence;
    public $factor;
    public $code;
    public $key;
    public $secure;
    public $token;
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $ctime;
    public $cdate;
    public $cr_code;
    public $status;

    function __construct($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l)
    {
        $this->licence = $a;
        $this->factor = $b;
        $this->code = $c;
        $this->key = $d;
        $this->secure = $e;
        $this->token = $f;
        $this->name = $g;
        $this->email = $h;
        $this->ctime = $i;
        $this->cdate = $j;
        $this->cr_code = $k;
        $this->status = $l;
    }
}
$cathy = new verify($Licence_code , $Factor_code , $Verify_code , $Key_saz , $Secure , $Token , $Factor_name , $Factor_email , $Now_time , $Now_date , $Date_code , 1);
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `i_verfy`(`licence`, `factor`, `code`, `key`, `secure`, `token`, `name`, `email`, `ctime`, `cdate`, `cr_code`, `status`) VALUES (:licence, :factor, :code, :key, :secure, :token, :name, :email, :ctiem, :cdate, :cr_code, :status)");
$STH->execute((array)$cathy);
```

thanks .

Comment: You have a parameter called `ctiem`, but no such element in your array from your class.

Comment: `ctime` <-> `:ctiem`.

Comment: What is this `$STH->execute((array)$cathy);`?

Comment: Thank guys ! I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in your query.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `i_verfy`(`licence`, `factor`, `code`, `key`, `secure`, `token`, `name`, `email`, `ctime`, `cdate`, `cr_code`, `status`) VALUES (:licence, :factor, :code, :key, :secure, :token, :name, :email, :ctime, :cdate, :cr_code, :status)");
```